# For Loop on Lua

Tags: loops, for-loop, lua

My assignment is how to do a for loop. I have figured it out in terms of numbers but cannot figure it out in terms of names. I would like to create a for loop that runs down a list of names. Following is what I have so far:

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
for names = 1, 3 do
  print (names)
end
```

I have tried some other things but it just doesn't work, the terminal always just lists 1, 2, 3... What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Your problem is simple:

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
for names = 1, 3 do
  print (names)
end
```

This code first declares a global variable called `names`. Then, you start a for loop. The for loop declares a *local* variable that just happens to be called `names` too; the fact that a variable had previously been defined with `names` is entirely irrelevant. Any use of `names` inside the for loop will refer to the *local* one, not the global one.

The for loop says that the inner part of the loop will be called with `names = 1`, then `names = 2`, and finally `names = 3`. The for loop declares a *counter* that counts from the first number to the last, and it will call the inner code once for each value it counts.

What you actually wanted was something like this:

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
for nameCount = 1, 3 do
  print (names[nameCount])
end
```

The [] syntax is how you access the members of a Lua table. Lua tables map "keys" to "values". Your array automatically creates keys of integer type, which increase. So the key associated with "Joe" in the table is 2 (Lua indices always start at 1).

Therefore, you need a for loop that counts from 1 to 3, which you get. You use the count variable to access the element from the table.

However, this has a flaw. What happens if you remove one of the elements from the list?

```
names = {'John', 'Joe'}
for nameCount = 1, 3 do
  print (names[nameCount])
end
```

Now, we get `John Joe nil`, because attempting to access values from a table that don't exist results in `nil`. To prevent this, we need to count from 1 to the *length* of the table:

```
names = {'John', 'Joe'}
for nameCount = 1, #names do
  print (names[nameCount])
end
```

The `#` is the length operator. It works on tables and strings, returning the length of either. Now, no matter how large or small `names` gets, this will always work.

However, there is a more convenient way to iterate through an array of items:

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
for i, name in ipairs(names) do
  print (name)
end
```

`ipairs` is a Lua standard function that iterates over a list. This style of `for` loop, the iterator for loop, uses this kind of iterator function. The `i` value is the index of the entry in the array. The `name` value is the value at that index. So it basically does a lot of grunt work for you.

Comment: So, for with ipairs() works as foreach() in other languages

Comment: Great answer, I would just add that in the final example it is fairly customary to use `_` when the var is unused. e.g. `names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
for _, name in ipairs(names) do
  print (name)
end`

Answer (score 21):

By reading online ([tables tutorial](http://lua-users.org/wiki/TablesTutorial)) it seems tables behave like arrays so you're looking for:

**Way1**

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
for i = 1,3 do print( names[i] ) end
```

**Way2**

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
for k,v in pairs(names) do print(v) end
```

---

**Way1** uses the table `index/key` , on your table `names` each element has a key starting from 1, for example:

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
print( names[1] ) -- prints John
```

So you just make `i` go from 1 to 3.

On **Way2** instead you specify what table you want to run and assign a variable for its key and value for example:

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', myKey="myValue" }
for k,v in pairs(names) do print(k,v) end
```

prints the following:

```
1   John
2   Joe
myKey   myValue
```

Comment: You read the tables tutorial, but you didn't see `ipairs`? Or the part where `pairs` doesn't have to return the key values in any particular order?

Comment: I actually used `ipairs` at first but when I added the `myKey="myValue"` example that needs `pairs` for the non-numeric key I decided to change the rest for `pairs` as well. I'm sorry if I omitted that the order is not guaranteed with pairs but I left the link right there for him to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
names = {'John', 'Joe', 'Steve'}
for names = 1, 3 do
  print (names)
end
```

1. You're deleting your table and replacing it with an int
2. You aren't pulling a value from the table

Try:

```
names = {'John','Joe','Steve'}
for i = 1,3 do
    print(names[i])
end
```

Comment: Downvoter: please provide a *valid* reason for downvoting. Even though I think the answer is misleading in that `names` (the integer counter) as declared in the `for` scope introduces a local variable, which shadows the `names` (the table array) as declared in the global scope.