# For loops LUA Different Types

Tags: for-loop, lua

I wanted to learn more about for loops, as far as I know there are different types?

For instance,

```
for i = 1, 5 do
    print("hello")
end
```

^ I know about this one, it's going to print hello 5 times, but there are others like the one below which I do not understand, specifically the **index** bit (does that mean it is number 1?) and what is the **ipairs** for

```
for index, 5 in ipairs(x) do
    print("hello")
end
```

If there are any other types please let me know, I want to learn all of them and if you can provide any further reading I'd be more than greatful to check them out

Comment: All of this you'll find in pretty much every respectable Lua learning resource. There's just 2 `for` variants and you have them both in your question, anyway.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [For Loop on Lua](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616260/for-loop-on-lua)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can read in the Lua reference manual
[3.3.5 For Statement](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.5)

> The for statement has two forms: one numerical and one generic.
>
> The numerical for loop repeats a block of code while a control
>   variable runs through an arithmetic progression. It has the following
>   syntax:
>
> stat ::= for Name ‘=’ exp ‘,’ exp [‘,’ exp] do block end

Example:

```
for i = 1, 3 do
  print(i)
end
```

Will output

```
1    
2    
3
```

You seem familiar with that one. Read the reference manual section for more details.

> The generic for statement works over functions, called iterators. On
>   each iteration, the iterator function is called to produce a new
>   value, stopping when this new value is nil. The generic for loop has
>   the following syntax:
>
> stat ::= for namelist in explist do block end   namelist ::= Name {‘,’
>   Name}

Example:

```
local myTable = {"a", "b", "c"}
for i, v in ipairs(myTable) do
  print(i, v)
end
```

Will ouput

```
1  a
2  b
3  c
```

ipairs is one of those iterator functions mentioned:

> Returns three values (an iterator function, the table t, and 0) so
>   that the construction
>
> `for i,v in ipairs(t) do body end` will iterate over the key–value pairs `(1,t[1]), (2,t[2]), ...,` up to the first `nil` value.

Read more about ipairs and pairs here:

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-pairs

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-ipairs

Of course you can implement your own iterator functions!

Make sure you also read:

[Programming in Lua: 7 Iterators and the Generic for](https://www.lua.org/pil/7.html)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It will print hello 5 times

According to this answer on [Difference between pairs, ipairs, and next?](https://scriptinghelpers.org/questions/2725/difference-between-pairs-ipairs-and-next)

> `ipairs` does the exact same thing as `pairs`, but with a slight twist to it.
>
> `ipairs` runs through the table, until it finds a `nil` value, or a value that is non-existent, if that makes sense. So, if you ran the script I showed you for pairs, but just replaced pairs with ipairs, it would do the exact same thing

Comment: Where's that quote from? You should cite your sources.